# Is there a way to configure password encoder for default password?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I use overridden values for spring security username and password. Following properties are in my `application.properties`.

```
spring.security.user.name=myUser
spring.security.user.password=myPassword
spring.security.user.roles=admin
```

I would like to encrypt the password value as follows:

```
spring.security.user.name=myUser
spring.security.user.password={bcrypt}hashedpassword valuevalue
spring.security.user.roles=admin
```

I added `PasswordEncoder` in my `SpringConfig`:

```java
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

In some example I noticed that there is for `AuthenitcationManagerBuilder` but I do not know what datasource should be used. What else do I need to use encrypted password for default user?

```java
@Autowired
public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
```

Adding my Spring Security config as a reference:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/custom").hasRole("admin")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .httpBasic();

        http
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grabbing:

```text
$2a$12$7Bg57uTtN7GWIdiqRW4h5e/aOUFagHwkEGv9byUr0bb/QbUU8S4rS
```

for input:

```text
hello
```

... from (e.g. thx): https://bcrypt-generator.com/

With:

- [spring-starter (web, security)](https://start.spring.io/#!dependencies=web,security),
- `application.properties`:

  ```properties
  spring.security.user.password={bcrypt}$2a$12$7Bg57uTtN7GWIdiqRW4h5e/aOUFagHwkEGv9byUr0bb/QbUU8S4rS
  ```
- and any (rest)controller:

  ```java
  package com.example.demo;

  import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
  import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
  import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
  import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
  import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

  @SpringBootApplication
  @RestController
  public class DemoApplication {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
     }

     //  @Bean
     //  public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
     //   return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
     //  }

     @GetMapping("secured")
     public String secured() {
      return "Hello Admin";
     }
  }
  ```
- and *without additional config*,
- we can login with `user=user` and `password=hello`.

Adding:

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
  return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

*breaks* this behavior!! To "fix it", we can (`application.properties`):

```
spring.security.user.password=$2a$12$7Bg57uTtN7GWIdiqRW4h5e/aOUFagHwkEGv9byUr0bb/QbUU8S4rS
```

.. omit the "tag" `{bcrypt}`! ...

Responsible for "tags"/capable of several algorithms is the `DelegatingPasswordEncoder`, which is auto configured (via `[AuthenticationConfiguration|HttpSecurityConfiguration].LazyPasswordEncoder` ..if *no other* PasswordEncoder bean found) and uses
`PasswordEncoderFactories` behind the scenes, like ([currently](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/factory/PasswordEncoderFactories.java)) this:

> ```
> @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
> public static PasswordEncoder createDelegatingPasswordEncoder() {
>   String encodingId = "bcrypt";
>   Map<String, PasswordEncoder> encoders = new HashMap<>();
>   encoders.put(encodingId, new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
>   encoders.put("ldap", new org.springframework.security.crypto.password.LdapShaPasswordEncoder());
>   encoders.put("MD4", new org.springframework.security.crypto.password.Md4PasswordEncoder());
>   encoders.put("MD5", new org.springframework.security.crypto.password.MessageDigestPasswordEncoder("MD5"));
>   encoders.put("noop", org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
>   encoders.put("pbkdf2", Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder.defaultsForSpringSecurity_v5_5());
>   encoders.put("pbkdf2@SpringSecurity_v5_8", Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder.defaultsForSpringSecurity_v5_8());
>   encoders.put("scrypt", SCryptPasswordEncoder.defaultsForSpringSecurity_v4_1());
>   encoders.put("scrypt@SpringSecurity_v5_8", SCryptPasswordEncoder.defaultsForSpringSecurity_v5_8());
>   encoders.put("SHA-1", new org.springframework.security.crypto.password.MessageDigestPasswordEncoder("SHA-1"));
>   encoders.put("SHA-256",
>           new org.springframework.security.crypto.password.MessageDigestPasswordEncoder("SHA-256"));
>   encoders.put("sha256", new org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder());
>   encoders.put("argon2", Argon2PasswordEncoder.defaultsForSpringSecurity_v5_2());
>   encoders.put("argon2@SpringSecurity_v5_8", Argon2PasswordEncoder.defaultsForSpringSecurity_v5_8());
>   return new DelegatingPasswordEncoder(encodingId, encoders);
> }
> ```

#### EDIT:

No, also introducing:

```
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
          .csrf()
          .disable()
          .authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/secured").hasRole("admin")
          .anyRequest()
          .authenticated()
          .and()
          .httpBasic();

      http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
      return http.build();
    }
  }
}
```

Plus:

```properties
spring.security.user.roles=admin
```

Doesn't change my observations:

- When "custom password encoder"
- and `$2a$12$7Bg57uTtN7GWIdiqRW4h5e/aOUFagHwkEGv9byUr0bb/QbUU8S4rS`

  - can login with `user:hello` (and view `/secured` response)
- with default/-out password encoder
- and `{bcrypt}$2a$12$7Bg57uTtN7GWIdiqRW4h5e/aOUFagHwkEGv9byUr0bb/QbUU8S4rS`

  - can login with `user:hello` (and view `/secured` response)

(it only switches from form to basic login:)

Test (good/app config):

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.httpBasic;
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.response.SecurityMockMvcResultMatchers.authenticated;
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.response.SecurityMockMvcResultMatchers.unauthenticated;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@WebMvcTest
class WithAppConfigTest {

  @Autowired
  MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test
  void expectAccess() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(
        get("/secured")
            .with(httpBasic("user", "hello"))
    ).andExpectAll(
        authenticated(),
        status().isOk(),
        content().string("Hello Admin"));
  }

  @Test
  void expectUnauthorized() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(
        get("/secured")
            .with(httpBasic("user", "wrong"))
    ).andExpectAll(
        unauthenticated(),
        status().isUnauthorized(),
        content().bytes(new byte[0]));
  }
}
```

Test forbidden:

```
@WebMvcTest(properties = "spring.security.user.roles=foo,bar,baz")
class WithFakeConfigTest {

  @Autowired
  MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test
  void expectForbidden() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(
        get("/secured")
            .with(httpBasic("user", "hello"))
    ).andExpectAll(
        authenticated(), // !, but:
        status().isForbidden(),
        content().bytes(new byte[0]));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am unable to load the example project from the first bullet. Can you send it again?

Comment: https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.0.0&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=web,security (better? both seem to work for me;(

Comment: oh, i used no config (except this one application.properties-entry) ..at all

Comment: Perhaps there is a different behavior when http basich auth configuration is added. No idea.

Comment: see edit, ..back to my question: where/what is problem?

Comment: I still receive 401 unauthorized when deleting @bean for password encoder from my config and use 

spring.security.user.name=myUser
spring.security.user.password={bcrypt}$2a$12$Svh4zYPZqKvUEo0/U6YloO.ExlIllcSP4G04b31/KGXjrzp/hFROy
spring.security.user.roles=admin

Comment: Maybe annotations are the problem here - Configuration,
EnableWebSecurity

Comment: oh, sorry, i indeed forgot @Configuration, but double-checked now and wrote test

Comment: maybe you can reproduce it by adding  .authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/secured").hasRole("admin")
to your current config

Comment: i also tried that...but authorization..and authentication.... (it seems to be/you seem to have an authentication problem ...401 :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250045/discussion-between-skywalker-and-xerx593).

Comment: I also [tested](https://bcrypt-generator.com/) your `{bcrypt}$2a$12$Svh4zYPZqKvUEo0/U6YloO.ExlIllcSP4G04b31/KGXjrzp/hFROy` against `myPassword` ..and had a match ;( ..glad: you found it!? Thanks for accept! ..back to my question: what was the problem?:)

Comment: You were absolutely right! It is working without any encoder and adding {bcrypt}hashedvalue in properties file for password. Perhaps it was a building issue. When I reloaded the project and added {bcrypt] build it again it worked. Thanks for your time :)